Discrepant baroque sheet music and codas
I downloaded several Scarlatti keyboard pieces from IMSLP annotated by Gouin. For instance 119 has a nice little left hand run. In the sheet music, it's annotated once, in most performances it's done twice and YouTubers who show the sheet music show the run twice. I don't see any coda in the version I have. Are these just apples and oranges interpretations of the same song? Or is the IMSLP version wrong? Or am I missing some secret codas somewhere?
Huge edit: I'm an idiot because this particular section does in fact annotate the double run. The more pertinent example might be Sonata 87. After I look at the sheet music, the 6th system clearly shows the repeat indicated (which I missed).


Could you be more specific, or perhaps post a YouTube link that demonstrates what you're describing. The run is played twice in Gouin's edition by virtue of the fact that the entire A section is played twice (repeat sign at m. 95). But since you mention a code, are you saying the YouTuber's play ||: A :||: B :|| A ||?

I listened to two recordings — Irena Koblar and Jeno Jando — and both play it as written — ||: A :||: B :|| — so the run I assume you're referring to (m. 34) occurs twice because of the written repeat.

You seem to have overlooked the repeat signs.  These are typically a double barline with two dots on one side or the other (or both), indicating a section of music to be played more than once.  In the baroque and classical periods, this is almost always twice, so you'll see some special notation if not.
The coda has a slightly different purpose -- it is a different conclusion that is tacked on to a piece, usually in ternary form, so that instead of being in ABA form, it's ABA' or even ABAC, where C is the coda.  This wasn't terribly common before the early 19th century, though there are probably examples in the 18th that I'm not aware of or have forgotten about.  Beethoven, for example, liked to have a big climactic ending, and recognized that having such music more than once in a movement would reduce its effectiveness, so is particularly noted for his innovative use of the coda, as mentioned in the Wikipedia article.
